# How to solve this congruence?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Given that $6^{12} ≡ 16\pmod {109}$. Is there a $k$ such that $16^k ≡ 6 \pmod {109}$? If there is, then find all the $k$'s.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

- $109$ is prime;
- if $16^k\equiv6\pmod{109}$ then $6^{12k-1}\equiv1\pmod{109}$;
- but you also know $6^{108}\equiv1\pmod{109}$;
- obtain a contradiction from the last two points.

Comment: How did u get that $6^{12k-1} ≡ 1$ (mod 109) ?

Comment: Hint: do you know anything about $6^{12}$?

Comment: I know where $6^{108}$ comes from, its because $\phi(109)=108$ since $109$ is prime and $109$ does not divide $6$. And $12$ is a factor of $108$, but I don't see how you put the $12k-1$...

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question, I can give an answer relying on the fact that $6$ has order $108$ mod $109$. So then we have the elements $6,6^2,6^3\dots 6^{168}\equiv1 \bmod 109$ are all different. the powers of $16$ are precisely $6^{12},6^{24},6^{36}\dots 6^{168}$ and no more, since they cycle (this is because $12$ divides $108$ which is the order of $6\bmod 108$, however you need to know the order of this beforehand).

In general if you want for an integer $k$ to exist so that  $(n^a)^k \equiv n \bmod m$ this happens if and only if $a$ and the order of $n$ mod $m$ are relatively prime.

---

I just noticed we can find a shortcut in this particular case. Notice $108$ is $2^2\cdot 3^2$. Now, notice the order of $6$ mod $109$  needs to be a nontrivial divisor of $108$ by Lagrange's theorem in group theory, this number cannot be relatively prime to $12$ because of the prime decompositon of $108$, so you don't actually have to calculate the order of $6$ to know, although this only works because $12$ contains all of the prime divisors of $108$ in its prime factorization.

Comment: You don't actually need to know the order of $6$ - just as well, because that's a fair bit of calculation.  You can use the relation $6^{12k}\equiv6$ to show that $6\equiv1$ which of course is a contradiction.

Comment: see the bottom of the solution

Comment: Yes, saw that, but in fact you don't even need to consider the order of $6$ at all.

Comment: you do, for example $16^2$ does have a power so that $(16^2)^k\equiv 16 \bmod 109$

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the relevance of that comment at all.  In this case you can solve the problem without knowing anything about the order of $6$.

Comment: yeah, that's what I wrote at the bottom part of the solution, but if we change $12$ by $3,9,2$ or $4$ the result depends on the order of $6$ mod $109$.

Comment: the only reason why we don't need to consider the order of $6$ in this case is because $12$ contains every prime divisor in the decomposition of $108$.

Comment: Do you see what I am saying?

Comment: Probably true, but the OP asked that specific question and so there is indeed no need to consider the order.

Comment: hmm, I think differently, I had never done this problem before, so I first characterized those cases when $n^a$ has a power that is congruent to $n$, and after doing the characterization I found a way to solve the problem, they are different approaches to the problem, sure yours is more direct, but I don't think my approach is worse because it is not as direct, because it generalizes (not a lot, but still). I think both ideas have their value.